Let $K$ be a local field and $l$ a $|k|^n-1$ primitive root of unity ($k$:= residue field). Why is $[K(l):K] = n$, $K(l)/K$ unramified and unique?
Let $K$ be a local field and $l$ a $|k|^n-1$ primitive root of unity ($k$ := residue field of $K$) with $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
My Question:
I don't understand why:
$ 1.[K(l):K] = n$
$2.K(l)/K$ is unramified.
$2.K(l)/K$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) unarmified extension of $K$ of degree n.
My Idear:
$1.$ I tried to find the minimal polynomial of $l$, but without success.
$2/3.$ I think it should be possible to use the same argument that you use to prove the existence and uniqueness of the inertia field for a finite extension of local fields T/K. But I am struggling to show that there exists a local field T/K with ($t:=$ residue field of $T$) $|t|$=|k|^n.
